# MusicXML Division and Duration

Tags: division, duration, music-notation, musicxml

I have an MXL file from some test suite in which the first measure says Division is 8 (i.e. 8 units per quarter note).

Measure 4 is in 3/4 time and has the following rest:

```
<note>
    <rest measure="yes"/>
    <duration>24</duration>
    <voice>1</voice>
</note>
```

I would expect to see `<dot/>` here. As 24 divided by 8 is 3, am I supposed to infer that this note should be dotted? Does this mean I'll have to write code for a special case where `<dot/>` is missing but the note is clearly supposed to be dotted?

I'm confused by this representation. I wish they'd made the `type` attribute mandatory myself... If anyone could explain how dotted and tuplet durations are supposed to be represented, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I don't know the answer to the question, but I would point out that there's no evidence that the MusicXML experts monitor this forum. I'd suggest signing up to the list/forum at http://www.makemusic.com/musicxml/specification Meanwhile I'm deleting the XML tag, since you're clearly not interested in answers from people whose primary expertise is in XML.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, if anyone else reads this then at the time of writing makemusic don't have a forum for questions relating to the spec / interpreting the spec, however I have just noticed the mailing list

Also thanks for removing the tag, I was being thoughtless! That will save me a lot of unwanted attention :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why should that note be dotted? If the division is 8, that means 8 units represent a quarter note. So 24 represents three quarter notes which in the case of 3/4 time is an entire bar rest.

As for tuplets I was curious about that also. Here is an example taken from the music xml site's tutorial piece '[apres un reve](http://www.musicxml.com/tutorial/notation-basics/looks-vs-sounds/)'. This is also in 3/4, with 24 divisions. The time-modification attributes specify the ratio of the tuplet, in this case a triplet of three eight notes.

```
    <time-modification>
      <actual-notes>3</actual-notes>
      <normal-notes>2</normal-notes>
    </time-modification>
```

The time modification above shows that **three eighth notes take the duration that two normally would**.

```
  <note default-x="92">
    <pitch>
      <step>E</step>
      <alter>-1</alter>
      <octave>5</octave>
    </pitch>
    <duration>8</duration>
    <tie type="stop"/>
    <voice>1</voice>
    <type>eighth</type>
    <time-modification>
      <actual-notes>3</actual-notes>
      <normal-notes>2</normal-notes>
    </time-modification>
    <stem default-y="-40">down</stem>
    <beam number="1">begin</beam>
    <notations>
      <tied type="stop"/>
      <tuplet bracket="no" number="1" placement="above" type="start"/>
    </notations>
  </note>
  <note default-x="122">
    <pitch>
      <step>D</step>
      <octave>5</octave>
    </pitch>
    <duration>8</duration>
    <voice>1</voice>
    <type>eighth</type>
    <time-modification>
      <actual-notes>3</actual-notes>
      <normal-notes>2</normal-notes>
    </time-modification>
    <stem default-y="-42">down</stem>
    <beam number="1">continue</beam>
    <lyric default-y="-80" number="1">
      <syllabic>single</syllabic>
      <text>que</text>
    </lyric>
  </note>
  <note default-x="162">
    <pitch>
      <step>C</step>
      <octave>5</octave>
    </pitch>
    <duration>8</duration>
    <voice>1</voice>
    <type>eighth</type>
    <time-modification>
      <actual-notes>3</actual-notes>
      <normal-notes>2</normal-notes>
    </time-modification>
    <stem default-y="-45">down</stem>
    <beam number="1">end</beam>
    <notations>
      <tuplet number="1" type="stop"/>
    </notations>
    <lyric default-y="-80" number="1">
      <syllabic>begin</syllabic>
      <text>char</text>
    </lyric>
  </note>
```

Comment: "Why should that note be dotted? If the division is 8, that means 8 units represent a quarter note. So 24 represents three quarter notes which in the case of 3/4 time is an entire bar rest."

Yup, I totally understand that, but as it's one note I would notate that as a dotted minim (dotted half) which is why I would have expected the <dot/> tag

Cheers for the duplet example too that's really helpful!

Comment: No problem. There's more info about the tuplet with mixed note durations in the musicxml-tutorial.pdf too, for 'an optional normal-type element that is used when the type of the note does not match the type of the normal-notes in the triplet.'

Answer (score 7):

Yes, there are musicXML experts monitoring this forum :-)
A whole measure rest is a symbol on its own. You don't need to/are not allowed to extend it with a dot.

Comment: Bob's right. The measure="yes" tag implies that it takes up the length of a measure but is represented as a whole rest -- this is standard in music notation. There is also a musicxml mailing list, btw.

Comment: What Bob and Michael said. Also, the direct link to the MusicXML mailing list is http://www.makemusic.com/musicxml/mailing-list. We do hope to move the mailing list to a forum later this year.

Comment: The MusicXML forum is now available at http://forums.makemusic.com/viewforum.php?f=12. The mailing list archives are now searchable there.

Answer (score 4):

The `<dot/>` element is only used when there is a dot in the score. In your example we have a full measure rest that doesn't have a dot. It would look like this:

[image]

If you on the other hand would like to have a rest that reflects the duration of the measure, it would look like this:

[image]

And the xml code would be this:

```
  <note>
    <rest />
    <duration>24</duration>
    <voice>1</voice>
    <type>half</type>
    <dot />
  </note>
```

In your example the `type` attribute isn't needed because the rest attribute `measure="yes"` already tell us what the rest should look like.